# Мне нужно реализовать скрипт(функцию) которая будет выполнять post ajax запрос на чистом js

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, post

Есть кнопки форм и по клику они должны отправлять данные формы в php файл.
Нужно одной функцией реализовать возможность, в зависимости от кнопки, данные которые там будут передаваться, но сколько не пробовал в голову лезет только хардкод.

Есть вот такой код:

```
const saleButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.sale-button', '.sale-button2', '.sale-button3', '.sale-button4', '.sale-button5', '.sale-button-calc')

function ajaxBit() {

}

saleButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = '/wp-content/themes/php/php.php';
    const params =;
    request.open("POST", url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.addEventListener("readystatechange", () => {
      if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
      }
    });
    request.send(params);
  })
})
```

Comment: Если это WordPress, то вот это вот работать не будет нормально `const url = '/wp-content/themes/php/php.php';`

Comment: Ну и конкретная проблема то в чем?